# Does anyone know how to execute a Selenium test file (.side) in Azure DevOps release pipeline? I'm using command line

Tags: azure, azure-devops, selenium-side-runner

*Sorry for my ignorance.

I'm using selenium-side-runner and I'm targeting the W: drive on the target server where the website is being deployed to and that also hosts the test file (.side). I just manually added the file to the server.

selenium-side-runner w:/SeleniumTestScripts/DevTap.side --output-directory w:/SeleniumTestScripts/Output --output-format=junit --debug --config-file w:/SeleniumTestScripts/config.yaml

Where do I physically put the .side file?  On the target deployment server?
It seems like it cannot locate them.

Do I need to add them in the Repo as part of the deployment process?

*

[image]

```
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9024237Z ##[section]Starting: 3) Run exported Selenium IDE script (.side)
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9143575Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9143885Z Task         : Command line
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9144207Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9144491Z Version      : 2.182.0
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9144713Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9145029Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2021-05-10T18:09:08.9145385Z ==============================================================================
2021-05-10T18:09:11.3248098Z Generating script.
2021-05-10T18:09:11.3351185Z Script contents:
2021-05-10T18:09:11.3357235Z selenium-side-runner w:/SeleniumTestScripts/DevTap.side --output-directory w:/SeleniumTestScripts/Output --output-format=junit --debug --config-file w:/SeleniumTestScripts/config.yaml
2021-05-10T18:09:11.3685160Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-05-10T18:09:11.3927321Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\1a8c7b60-5446-4f73-bd39-b1e3154b7574.cmd""
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6351195Z [34mdebug[39m:   Could not load w:/SeleniumTestScripts/config.yaml
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6384711Z [34mdebug[39m:   {
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6385268Z   capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' },
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6385815Z   params: {},
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6386185Z   runId: '1d920a92a721072218013322137b7a61',
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6386612Z   path: 'C:\\npm\\prefix\\node_modules\\',
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6386988Z   server: undefined,
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6387326Z   timeout: 15000,
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6387685Z   baseUrl: undefined,
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6388053Z   outputFormat: [Function: junit]
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6388422Z }
2021-05-10T18:09:11.6821585Z ##[section]Finishing: 3) Run exported Selenium IDE script (.side)
```

Comment: You can try to follow this official [lab](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/).